# Laraver problem show URL of stored file in blade view

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel API to store files on Laravel local.  `File_path` is  `/app/Files/{id_message}/`. Variables `id_message` and `file_path` are stored in databese table `files`.

when i uploud file i have this situation:

table `files`

```
id    id_message    file_path
1     000001        /app/Files/000001/w2YANqYe82itnLSsIa.zip
```

Im loosing mind how to show in blade View for download:

```
<td><a href ="{{ asset ('app/Files/'.$id_message.'/'.$file_name) }}">Download</a></td>
```

I honestly went through the available materials on the web, but I don't know how to do it

I will be happy for any help.

```
function fileUpload(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    
    $idParameter = $request->id_message=$request->id_message;

    $result=$request->file('file_path')->store('Files/'.$idParameter);
    
    $file = new File;
    $file->id_message=$idParameter;
    $file->file_path=$result;
    $file->save();
}
```

`filesystems.php` :

```
'disks' => [
        'private' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/Files'),
    ],
```

Comment: you cannot access `/app/Files/` this folder via `url` put all file in `storgae` or `public` then you can access via url .. or it would be great if you put your upload file code

Comment: code added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s you store file via `store()` method so you can get file url via `Storage::url()`

```php
<td><a href ="{{ Storage::url('app/Files/'.$id_message.'/'.$file_name) }}">Download</a></td>
```

like this

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

> **NOTE** : -  it will work  if driver is public

Comment: how can be defined variable ````id_message```` ? know i have Error : ````Undefined variable: id_message````

Comment: it should come from database for that particular data